# .put method for updating password in mocha chai requests not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

My code:

```
const model = require('../db/models/user');
const describe = require('mocha').describe;
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let chai = require('chai');
let server = require('../server');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Test user registration, login, update password', () => {
    beforeEach((done) => {
        // Reset user mode before each test
        model.User.remove({}, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            done();
        })
    });
```

Now, I get the error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   '_id' of null

in the route itself, specifically:

```
router.put('/me/update-password', async (req, res, next) => {
    const {body} = req;
    const auth = req;
    const userId = auth._id; // problem on this line!

// rest of code...

});
```

So, after registration and logging in (which works fine, as it should!), I am having a lot of problems to update the password. In the `params` I am sending generated token and in the `body` is the password field with new password. On live example (for example Postman) it works as it should, but in tests it simply does not.

I really have no idea and have lost a lot of my time over this already (3 days).

Can someone please take a look suggest solution?

Much appreciated.

Updated with auth.js:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const isAu = function(req) {
  return jwt.verify(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1], 'secret', function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      return null;
    }

    return decoded;
  });
};

module.exports = isAu;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where is `isAuthenticated` defined?

Comment: @ScottRudiger, it is in the separate file, will update in a min

Comment: @ScottRudiger, updated.

Comment: what is your Request Authorization header value you used in postman test?

Comment: @Milan, it is the jwt token of logged user.

Comment: if your token is Bearer token try setting Authorization header in chai to : .set('Authorization', \`Bearer ${token}\`)

Comment: It is `Token` not `Bearer`

Comment: Strongtu - if you update / remove original code from the questions that is referenced in the answer other people would not be able to see where the problem was and learn from it... I suggest that you leave the original post if the answer that answered it was correct

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** 
Since OP changed the original question after it has been answered here is the link to original: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55064109/1

=======================================

JWT verify method accepts Authorization token - you are fetching that correctly by splitting Authorization header string in order to fetch token.

HTTP Authorization header string hold Authentication scheme type (Bearer, Basic, Digest, etc)  and the token value

`Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIXVCJ9...TJVA95OrM7E20RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ`

but your `Authorization` header in the Chai request only holds the value of the token and not the Authentication scheme type.

Assumin your Authentication scheme is *Bearer* you need to set that in your Chai request Authorization header:

```
...
chai.request(server)
 .put('/api/me/update-password')
 .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
 .send(`${updatedPassword}`)
 .end((error, response) => {
    assert.equal(response.status, 200);
    done();
 });
...
```

On the other hand, in case you do not specify Authentication type in the request authorization header than you should send it like that to JWT to veirfy:

```
const isAuthenticated = function(req) {
  return jwt.verify(req.headers.authorization, 'secret', function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      return null;
    }

    return decoded;
  });
};
```

Comment: It is `Token`, not `Bearer`

Comment: it is just the matter how you send the string to jwt.verify. in your code you are splitting the header string and sending second string. Is this the string you have set in chai Authorization header?